ELI5: PCA and timeseries (stock) data and the meanings of scores and loadings
I got to try to use PCA for clustering Time Series Data (stock closing prices over a period of time). What I've done so far is:

aquire data for a lot of stocks (each column represents a share, each row represents one observation)
normalize the data
get the coefficient matrix
do the pca on the matrix

My current step is now to understand the result, especially the scores and loadings and use it to cluster the shares, not the observations.
And while I read a lot and discussed this topic a lot with chatGPT, I simply can't get what is the meaning of the loadings and the scores in this case, and which of those values would help me in clustering. As soon as I get this, I could simply use clustering mechanisms like k-means clustering for the final practical step.
So basically my question is: can you ELI5 what the meanings of scores and loadings are in my example and what to use them for?
Edit: After reading your comments it became clear to me, that I lack the general understanding of the scores. Sadly, even after reading the suggested answer of the other thread, I can't wrap my head around it, so I will simply show my problem and hope that someone is kind enough to explain it directly
Result of the PCA with the normal data:

Basically, i did a pca on my timeseries data (each column containts the timeseries data for 1 share) and got this as a result. The loadings (left side) are completly fine for me, but the plot, which shows the scores, displays each observation, instead of each share
Result of the PCA with transposed data:

Here i did the same with the transposed data, so each row contains timeseries information about a share. As a result, the loadings are done for each observation, but the plot of the scores shows me each share.
Since it is my target to cluster the shares (and not the observations), and analyze the result, I wanted the loadings AND the Scoreplot of the shares.
So please, ELI5, what is the mathematical reason for this?

Welcome to the site. What is your goal? To reduce dimensionality? To do some exploratory data analysis on the shares? That will help elicit an answer.

Hi Rick, thank you!

Hi Rick, thank you! My target is to cluster the shares based on their principle components. So just as an example, if I see that, after the pca, pc1 and pc2 explain a lot of the variance, I would use a cluster algo like k-means on the Scores of each share and compare the Clusters to the result of other time series cluster mechanisms

Did the suggested answer help you? This has been flagged as a duplicate, so hopefully that helped. If not, you can try to edit this to explain why you still don't understand.

"I simply can't get what is the meaning of the loadings and the scores in this case" I interpreted this as "I can't get the meaning how PCA works". But I see now that you added 'in this case'. Why is this case different?

Thanks again for your comments. After reading the answer from the other thread I updated this one to better define my problem. Thank you already for your help!

"what is the mathematical reason for this?" The reason for what? That the rows change when you transpose the matrix?
